# Bigquery "NOT IN" comparison performance too slow

Tags: google-bigquery

It seems something has changed with "NOT IN" comparison? The performance is very poor compared to a month ago.

I have query like this:

```
SELECT SOMETHING FROM X WHERE KEY NOT IN (SELECT KEY FROM Y)
```

Y returns 45,000 keys.

X contains 84,000 records.

This query takes more than 1 minutes to complete while using IN comparison only takes few seconds.

The actual query is more complex than this but I have tried to remove the complex part and pretty much narrow it down to the cause as the "NOT IN" comparison.

I had run this query back in August with much larger dataset and it wasn't like this slow. I am wondering if there was any changes in "NOT IN" operation. And if there is any workaround to improve the performance.

[Execution Details Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xWGi.png)

Comment: Would a LEFT JOIN with WHERE key IS NULL solve this problem?

Comment: The LEFT JOIN solution works very well. It only take seconds to execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These 3 queries should behave in a similar way (same results and similar performance), but somehow `NOT IN` and `NOT EXISTS` is behaving way slower right now.

I created a bug to track this performance hit, as it should only be transitory (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/116839201).

```
SELECT tags, COUNT(*) c, ANY_VALUE(b.value)
FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions` a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT x.value FROM UNNEST((
  SELECT APPROX_TOP_COUNT(tags, 10000) 
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions` 
)) x ) b
ON a.tags=b.value
WHERE b.value IS NULL
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 1000

12 seconds, fh-bigquery:US.bquijob_3c0fdf82_1661f6f3dd1

SELECT tags, COUNT(*) c
FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions` 
WHERE tags NOT IN(SELECT x.value FROM UNNEST((
  SELECT APPROX_TOP_COUNT(tags, 10000) 
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions` 
)) x)
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC, 1
LIMIT 1000

> 400 seconds, fh-bigquery:US.bquijob_766cc8ab_1661f7023bb

SELECT tags, COUNT(*) c
FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions` 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT x.value FROM UNNEST((
  SELECT APPROX_TOP_COUNT(tags, 10000) 
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions` 
)) x WHERE tags=value)
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC, 1
LIMIT 1000

> 400 seconds, fh-bigquery:US.bquijob_59a9d1e6_1661f59db40
```

Generally speaking: `NOT EXISTS` should be preferable to `NOT IN`, as it behaves better under null values.

Comment: Note that the issue has gotten worse - see latest stats https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/116839201#comment2